# Use of weights and exact argument for estimating weighted mean from a raster using a polygon

Tags: r, raster, terra

I am trying to understand the difference between `exact` and `weights` argument in the `extract` function in `terra` package. My ultimate goal is to do a weighted average of raster within a polygon

```
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v <- v[1:2,]
z <- rast(v, resolution=.1, names="test")
values(z) <- 1:ncell(z)
rf <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
x <- rast(rf)

head(terra::extract(x, v, weight = T, touches = T))
  
ID elevation weight
1  1        NA   0.08
2  1        NA   0.17
3  1       529   0.30
4  1       542   0.52
5  1       547   0.74
6  1       535   0.18
  
head(terra::extract(x, v, exact = T, touches = T))
ID elevation   fraction
1  1        NA 0.03471857
2  1        NA 0.11553771
3  1       529 0.23902885
4  1       542 0.45706171
5  1       547 0.68120503
6  1       535 0.12033581
```

Why the weight and fraction are different in both cases? When I try to compute the weighted mean:

```
terra::extract(x, v, fun = mean, weights = T, touches = T, na.rm = T)
ID elevation
1  1       NaN
2  2       NaN
  
terra::extract(x, v, fun = mean, exact = T, touches = T, na.rm = T)
ID elevation
1  1  467.3792
2  2  334.6856
```

Why does the first gives me NaN while the 2nd gives me some values. If I calculate it manually, I can see the weighted mean is what the `exact = T` is giving me so what is the use of `weights` argument?

```
test_df <- terra::extract(x, v, exact = T, touches = T, na.rm = T)
test_df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(wt_mean = weighted.mean(elevation, fraction, na.rm = T))
  
ID wt_mean
1    467.
2    335.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my version of "terra" the results are very similar.

```
library(terra)
#terra 1.6.53

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
v <- v[1:2,]
z <- rast(v, resolution=.1, names="test")
values(z) <- 1:ncell(z)
rf <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
x <- rast(rf)

terra::extract(x, v, fun = mean, weights = T, touches = T, na.rm = T)
#  ID elevation
#1  1  467.3934
#2  2  334.6551
terra::extract(x, v, fun = mean, exact = T, touches = T, na.rm = T)
#  ID elevation
#1  1  467.3792
#2  2  334.6856
```

The documentation says that with "weights", "the *approximate* fraction of each cell" is used whereas with "exact", "the *exact* fraction" is used.

The reason for having both is in part because the argument "weights" predates the argument "exact". "weights" was kept because it could be faster and close enough in most cases.

P.S., you can also do

```
exactextractr::exact_extract(x, st_as_sf(v), "mean")
#[1] 467.3792 334.6855
```

Comment: Okay. The version I have is: `1.6.17`. Let me update the packages and see if this fixed it

Comment: I reinstall the package: `install.packages("terra");library(terra)` and the version I have now is `1.6.47`. And this produces the right results